# Adding additional information under corrplot's x axis

Tags: r, plot, pca, cumsum, r-corrplot

I'm trying to add "cumulative proportional variance explained" (from PCA) under corrplot's x axis. I referenced `corrplot` manual but didn't find out any instruction for doing that. Below is the code I have at the moment using example data.

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
library("corrplot")

data(decathlon2)
decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]

res.pca <- PCA(decathlon2.active, graph = FALSE)
var <- get_pca_var(res.pca)
corrplot(var$cos2, is.corr=FALSE)

##getting cumulative variance explained from res.pca
variance <- res.pca$eig*100/sum(res.pca$eig)
cumvar <- cumsum(variance)
```

The problem is how to insert the `cumvar` information into the `corrplot`'s x-axis, such that they match with the corresponding `dim*` on top of the`corrplot`, which obviates the need to do a scree plot.

Does anyone know how to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display these numbers at the bottom of x-axis:

1. Repeating your calculations

   ```
   library("FactoMineR")
   library("factoextra")
   library("corrplot")

   data(decathlon2)
   decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]

   res.pca <- PCA(decathlon2.active, graph = FALSE)
   var <- get_pca_var(res.pca)

   variance <- res.pca$eig*100/sum(res.pca$eig)
   cumvar <- cumsum(variance)
   ```
2. Making a plot with extra space at the bottom

   ```
   corrplot(var$cos2, is.corr=FALSE, mar=c(4,0,0,0))
   ```
3. Adding proportion of variance explained under the cells:

   ```
   text(1:5, 0, round(cumvar[1:5], 2), xpd=TRUE)
   ```

And the result:

[image: result]